# Replacing Jar files within Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

I want to replace old jar file of lucene i.e. lucene 3.6.2.jar(marked in the following figure) with new lucene 4.3.0.jar. But I am a beginner in developing Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse. So I have no idea how to do it. Each time I am opening the window of build path I see no option to modify those jar files included in Tomcat library. I am working with Eclipse Juno. Please help me to fix this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see a jar file in Apache Tomcat libraries, it means you have it under the `${tomcat_home}/lib` folder. If you want to remove it from global `.classpath` you should remove it from lib folder manually and then refresh your project in eclipse.

Comment: But how should I add new Jar file there?

Comment: every jar file in ${tomcat_home}/lib folder places in global classpath so you can modify them to fit your needs

Comment: Yes I have copied it and refreshed Eclipse. But it is not showing in Eclipse

Comment: I'm tested it right now and it's OK, make sure to copy jar files in lib folder under tomcat directory(copy just jar file not directory containing jar file) and also check that tomcat which you copy jar files into it is same as tomcat you have in eclipse as runtime

Comment: remember to refresh your project in eclipse, right click on your project and choose refresh